Issue with Filters selected value being cached after change another slicer
I'm havin an issue with PowerBI slicers behavior.
So far, i have 2 tables:
Project



project
project_name




A
Project 1


B
Project 2



Category :
 category   category_name   project
 1          Category 1      A
 2          Category 2      A
 3          Category 3      A
 4          Category 4      B
 5          Category 5      B
 6          Category 6      B

Relationship:
project.project = category.project
Now I have two slicers: one for project_name, one for category_name (all are dropdown lists and single select)
My idea is the category filter will be changed after selecting the project in the project slicer.
For example:

I choose project A in Slicer Project -> There will be category names: Category 1, Category 2, Category 3 in Slicer Category. Like this:
And this behavior would be similar to Project 2
But there's an issue now is that if my selection now are Project 1, Category 1; then I pick Project 2 in Slicer Project, my expectation for this case would be Category 4, Category 5, Category 6 in the Slicer Category, But the Category 1 (which belongs to Project 1) would be cached when I switch the project from Project 1 -> Project 2.
Like the image below:

After this, if I choose Indicator 4 or 5 or 6, and click on the expand button for drop downlist again, the Indicator 1 is now disabled.

Has anyone ever experienced this?
Did I do sth wrong?
Thx in advanced!
I'm trying to create a measure to create but it seems impossible. Any ideas?

I agree on what you mentioned about how Power BI caches the slicer selections and maintains the state of a slicer even when the context changes like in your case you are switching the projects and the previously selected category from one project remains selected or gets disabled when switching to another project.
You can create a CC in your Category table to get the project_name based on the project relationship :
CategoryProjectName = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    Project[project_name],
    Project[project], 
    Category[project]
)

Instead of using the project_name from the Project table, now you can use the CategoryProjectName from the Category table in your slicer :


